# how to keep account of which user has posted which record in mongoDB database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jwt

I am working on MERN project, where users can post ads of their vehicles and other user can see these ads. I want that only the use who has submitted a vehicle ad will be allowed two delete that specific ad.I have to different mongoDB schema for user and vehicles ad and successfully storing and fetching users and vehicle data from mongoDB.I have no idea how this can be done. Can some guide me how it can be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add an identifier to your `Vehicles` collection to know which `User` is the owner of the `Vehicle`

```json
{
  "_id": "12345",
  "description": "Vehicle for sell",
  "userId": "Your user _id goes here or any other unique identifier for user"
}
```

and then upon request to Update / Delete an `ad` you check whether requesting user has same id as `userId` in `Vehicles` collection.h

Comment: but one thing there will be many ads with the same userId how can I find that specific ad that I want to delete among all the ads having same userId ?

Comment: suppose you have an endpoint for deleting that ad at DETELE /ad/:adId then upon request, you find a document matching both "adId" and "userId"

Comment: got it perfectly know